# Question on an approximation in pricing formula

Tags: pricing-formulae

I am reading the book *An Introduction to Financial Option Valuation*. The following on page 58 makes me confused:

> For the formula:
>   $\exp \left\{ -1.96\sigma \sqrt{t}+(\mu-0.5 \sigma^2)t \right\}$,
>
> if $t$ is small, then it is approximately equal to $\exp \left (-1.96 \sigma \sqrt{t} \right )$.
>
> Moreover, the second formula approximagely equals $1 - 1.96 \sigma \sqrt{t}$.

I don't understand how can we get the second and the third expression. If $t$ is very small, then $\sqrt{t}$ should be infinitesimal. Then, why has $(\mu-0.5 \sigma^2)t$ disappeared in the second formula, but not $-1.96 \sigma \sqrt{t}$?

Comment: I agree with the assumption QuantIbex stated at the very end. Not knowing the text but if the authors did not elaborate why they made such assumption then I find it a pretty weak treatise and without specific reasons (especially without establishing a relationship between sigma, mu, and t) such assumption could potentially even be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simplify notations, let $a:= -1.96\sigma$ and $b := \mu - 0.5\sigma^2$. The development in the book could be justified if both $a\sqrt{t}$ and $bt$ are small (close to zero), and if we have that $|a\sqrt{t}| > |bt|$.

Recall that

1. $\exp (x+y)= \exp(x)\exp(y)$,
2. $\exp(x)\approx 1 + x,\quad \text{if } x\approx 0$.

Then, using these properties we have
\begin{align}
\exp (a\sqrt{t} + bt)
 &= \exp (a\sqrt{t}) \exp (bt)\\
 &\approx \exp (a\sqrt{t})  (1 + bt) \\
 &\approx \exp (a\sqrt{t}),\tag{1} \\
 &\approx 1 + a\sqrt{t},
\end{align}
where the  approximation in (1) follows from the fact that $bt$ is (very) close to zero.

The fact that  $bt$ dissapeared but not $a\sqrt{t}$ comes from the fact that they probably assume that $|a\sqrt{t}| > |bt|$. This assumption should be explicitly stated or obvious from the context (given the typical values for $\sigma$ and $\mu$).

Comment: Answer downvoted, so deemed not useful. How could it be improved to become useful?

Comment: Yesterday,I saw two answers for my question.But now,only one left.I didn't vote any answer since it requires 15 reputation but I have only 1.Both your answers are helpful.Because the key point I didn't understand before reading your answer is that exp(x) approximates 1+x if x is infinitesimal.And I also made a mistake about x and the square root of x.If x is within (0,1),then,x must be smaller than square root of x.

Comment: The approximation $\exp (x) = 1 + x$ when $x$ is near $0$ comes from the [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of the exponential function. Another useful approximation is $\log (1 + x) = x$.

Comment: @Hebe, feel free to come back and vote once you've reach the required reputation threshold. As the author of the question you also have the option to accept one of the answers (http://quant.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: This is very basic maths, how can this be downvoted ?

Comment: By the way the condition $|at^{0.5}|>|bt|$ is not needed, it is equivalent to $|a/b|>|t^{0.5}|$, which is true for small t.

Comment: @lmorin Why are these conditions true for small $t$?

Comment: For non trivial cases, $|a/b|$ is a fixed number, we can make $|t^{O.5}|$ arbitrarily small by choosing t. So for t small enough, we will have $|a/b|> |t^{0.5}|$.

Comment: @lmorin: Sure, the constraint $a^2/b^2>t$ will be satisfied as $t \to 0$. But small $t$ does not imply $a^2/b^2>t$, unless the meaning of "small $t$" is that $t<a^2/b^2$.
So, one way or the other, one has to assume that $a^2/b^2>t$ (or one of its equivalent formulation) for given values of $a$, $b$, and $t$. Otherwise, the approximation should rather be $\exp (a\sqrt{t} + bt) \approx 1 + bt$.

Comment: "small t" is a common shortcut for saying "small enough t"

Comment: @lmorin: Sure, and here $t$ is small enough when at least $a^2/b^2>t$. So, once again, one way or the other on has to make this assumption.

Comment: Another way to see your condition is not good, $t= a^{2}/b^{2} - 0.0000001 $ will give you two term with the same value. If you don't mind the notation you will need to have $t << a^{2}/b^{2}$ as a condition, wich is usually expressed by "for small t".

Comment: Ok, there's probably no point in continuing this discussion; I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add this side note to Quantelbex' answer:

Both factors in $\exp(a\sqrt t)\exp(b t)$ go to one as $t$ goes to zero, but for small $t$, the $\exp(b t)$ term approaches one faster. For $t=\frac {a^2}{b^2}$ both factors  are the same, if $t$ is smaller than $\frac {a^2}{b^2}$, we have $\exp(a\sqrt t) > \exp(bt)$. Thus the approximation that $\exp(a \sqrt t + b t) \approx \exp(a \sqrt t)$ for small $t$.

Using the Taylor expansion for the exponential we can calculate the error that is made with this approximation:\begin{align}\exp(a \sqrt t + b t) - \exp(a\sqrt t) &= 1+a\sqrt t +b t + \frac 12 a^2 t +\mathcal O(t^{3/2}) - (1+a\sqrt t + \frac 12 a^2 t + \mathcal O(t^{3/2}))\\
&= b t + \mathcal O(t^{3/2})\end{align}

The second approximation is just the Taylor  expansion of the first one and the error is given by:
\begin{align}\exp(a \sqrt t + b t) - 1-a\sqrt t &= 1+a\sqrt t +b t + \frac 12 a^2 t +\mathcal O(t^{3/2}) - 1-a\sqrt t\\
&= (b + \frac 12 a^2) t + \mathcal O(t^{3/2})\end{align}

So in both cases the error vanishes linear in $t$, but in order to understand the error one makes, one needs to know $a$ and $b$ to know if the approximations are acceptable for the values of $t$ you consider.

Comment: (+1) for the nice and clear explanation. The condition $t<a^2/b^2$ is more intuitive formulation of the condition on $t$ than $|a\sqrt{t}|>|bt|$.

Comment: x ~ y does NOT imply $e^{x}$ ~ $e^{y}$